# Redirecting new tab on button click.(Response.Redirect) in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect, targets

I'm trying to open a page in new tab/window on button click.I tried in the google got this code but its not working.

Can anybody help me with this?

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="Server" Text="SUBMIT" 
     OnClick="btnNewEntry_Click" OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"/>

protected void btnNewEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("CMS_1.aspx");
}
```

When I use this I'm getting error saying

```
   Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'aspnetForm' is undefined.
```

Comment: What is your form's ID?  Have you tried to change the "aspnetForm" in `OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target..."` to the id of your `<form>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code should work just remove one thing from here but it'll do redirection from current page within existing window

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="Server" Text="SUBMIT" 

 OnClick="btnNewEntry_Click"/>    



protected void btnNewEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Response.Redirect("CMS_1.aspx");
 }
```

And if u wanna do the this via client side scripting
Use this way

```
<asp:Button ID="BTN" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="window.open('Default2.aspx')" />
```

According to me you should prefer the Client Side Scripting because just to open a new window server side will take a post back and that will be useless..

Comment: It's opening the window in new window.Can I do this in new tab.

Comment: the signature of `window.open` is `var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);` that means windowName should also be passed to `window.open` https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.open

Comment: To open a pop up in a tab, you should set how the pop up's are handled in browser. Ex : in IE8+, Go to internet options, General, Tabs section, set when pop up's are encountered section

Answer (score 13):

You can do something like this :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
    onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="document.forms[0].target = '_blank';" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Wouldn't you be better off with

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl="CMS_1.aspx" 
            Target="_blank">
    Click here
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Because, to replicate your desired behavior on an `asp:Button`, you have to call `window.open` on the `OnClientClick` event of the button which looks a lot less cleaner than the above solution. Plus `asp:HyperLink` is there to handle scenarios like this.

If you want to replicate this using an `asp:Button`, do this.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="Server" 
        Text="SUBMIT"
        OnClientClick="javascript:return openRequestedPopup();"/>
```

JavaScript function.

```
var windowObjectReference;

function openRequestedPopup() {
    windowObjectReference = window.open("CMS_1.aspx",
              "DescriptiveWindowName",
              "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
}
```

Comment: I know this.Is there no way to do with Button?.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up using. Temporarily sets target to _blank, then sets it back.

```
OnClientClick="var originalTarget = document.forms[0].target; document.forms[0].target = '_blank'; setTimeout(function () { document.forms[0].target = originalTarget; }, 3000);"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add following in header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function fixform() {
            if (opener.document.getElementById("aspnetForm").target != "_blank") return;

            opener.document.getElementById("aspnetForm").target = "";
            opener.document.getElementById("aspnetForm").action = opener.location.href;
            }
</script>
```

Then call `fixform()` in load your page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rout redirecting.

```
protected void btnNewEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.RedirectToRoute("CMS_1"); 
}
```

which requires to define your routing logic in Global.asax file that could be like that:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("CMS_1", "CMS_1", "~/CMS_1.aspx");
```

where any request by CMS_1 pattern in application scope will be redirecting to CMS_1.aspx, but in URL shows like www.yoursite.com/CMS_1